# Cassandra and Cqlsh

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh

```
issaouedraogo$ cassandra -f  
[0.002s][warning][gc] -Xloggc is deprecated. Will use -Xlog:gc:/usr/local/Cellar/cassandra/3.11.6_2/libexec/logs/gc.log instead.
intx ThreadPriorityPolicy=42 is outside the allowed range [ 0 ... 1 ]
Improperly specified VM option 'ThreadPriorityPolicy=42'
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

aslo Trying to run cqlsh I get the following error

```
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1': error(61, "Tried connecting to [('127.0.0.1', 9042)]. Last error: Connection refused")})
```

I personal do not know why?
I try all the ressources out there but it not working
Any anyone can help me out

Comment: This seems like a configuration issue, not a programming (cql) issue, as you don't have a Cassandra server running.

Comment: actuallly I think I do have it running 
IssaMacBook:bin issaouedraogo$ brew services start cassandra
Service `cassandra` already started, use `brew services restart cassandra` to restart.

Comment: So the service says it's running, but Cassandra can't run when JVM creation fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are most likely using an unsupported Java. You need to switch to Java 8 at least u151 but latest is preferable.

Also, using `services` to determine if Cassandra is running isn't a reliable way to check it. You should instead run `nodetool status`. Cheers!

Comment: Good call!  The `ThreadPriorityPolicy` is definitely symptomatic of a JDK that's "too new" for Cassandra.

Comment: Perfect that works for me, I downgrade to Java 8 and was able to run cassandra. Thanks for the input.